# How To Reload Page/Refresh Page After Dialog Close

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am have some problem reloading the page after when I click the yes button inside the dialog box. After when I click the yes button (to confirm, so the item can be deleted), I want the page to refresh/reload so I can see my current item.

Here is my code

```
<p:commandButton id="checkin" action="#{checkoutListBean.doCheckin(c.checkoutNumber)}"
   value="Checkin" >
<p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure you delete this?" 
   icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
<p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
   icon="ui-icon-check" />
<p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
 icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

This is my java method that is call when the button is click

```
public String doCheckin(long checki) {

    CheckoutDb.checkinBook(checki);
    getCheckoutList();

    return "checkoutList?facesRedirect=true";
}

public List getCheckoutList() {
    return checkoutList = CheckoutDb.selectCheckedOutBooks();
}
```

Any help please

Comment: You've made an error with "facesRedirect"

Comment: First of all the you are using wrong syntax for faces redirection, it should be `?faces-redirect=true`.

Comment: You would usually do an AJAX update though, instead of reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the redirect

```
  public String doCheckin(long checki) {

    CheckoutDb.checkinBook(checki);
    getCheckoutList();

    return "checkoutList?faces-redirect=true";
}

public List getCheckoutList() {
    return checkoutList = CheckoutDb.selectCheckedOutBooks();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have an action attached to the button labelled "Yes".

Something like :

```
<p:commandButton action="#{checkoutListBean.reloadPage()}" value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
   icon="ui-icon-check" />
```

Then in the bean:

```
public String reloadPage() {
    return "checkoutList?faces-redirect=true";
}
```